# Change just the regular math font in document

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have the following document and wish to replace only the regular (not italic) math font with Liberation Serif to match the rest of the document.

Is this possible?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\begin{document}

The normal text set in Liberation Serif and maths \textbf{also,} instead of Adobe Utopia as intended
        \[v_x(t) = \lim\limits_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Several iitems: (a) `fourier` package sets the base font to Adobe Utopia and redefines the maths encodings (documentation, p1); (b) `fontenc` is not needed when using `fontspec`; (c) use `\setmathrm{Liberation Serif}` to set the mathrm font.

Comment: Oh, and (d) remove the `no-math` option to `fontspec` so that it can update the maths fonts.